# How to store digits before and after decimal point, in different variables. PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

The purpose of my code is to separate the digits before, and after my code.

```
for x in NumberStr:
        if x == '.':
            DigitsBeforeDP = NumberStr[:(x-1)]
            DigitsAfterDP = NumberStr[(x+1):]
```

This is the code I've written, and I have no idea why I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 101, in 
    ConvertToText()
  File "...", line 97, in ConvertToText
    DigitsBeforeDP = NumberStr[:(x-1)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

It might have something to do with the fact the `NumberStr` is stored as a string?
Can anyone explain what I have done wrong, and tell me how to improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `str.split()` method.

```
before, after = number_str.split('.')
```

Also, the reason you were getting that error is because you were doing `(x-1)` but at that point in time `x` is a string, `'.'`, so you are telling the interpreter to do `('.' - 1)`, which is why it tells you it does not support `-` for `str` and `int`.

You probably meant to have `(NumberStr.indexOf(x) - 1)`

Comment: would this method fail if the use inputed an int. eg 15

Comment: Yes, but so would your original code. Is the input going to be an int or a string, or could it possible be both?

Comment: Actually, you're looking for a decimal point, how could the user ever enter an int?

Comment: The input is any float, which is then turned into a string, then split. Because the user can enter whatever he/she likes.

Comment: As long as you cast the float to a string, then yes, this will work fine.

Comment: Does doing `try: Number = float(Number)` test if the conversion is possible? or does it actually convert it?

Comment: It will do the conversion if possible, and raise an exception if not.  One great thing about python is that you can answer questions like this for yourself almost instantly, just by typing the code into the REPL.  You need an `except` clause, however.